# Python working in command prompt, but not working in server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python code that works in command prompt(Windows) using `python file.py` command, but when I copy this code and put it inside server, it does not work. (it gives me an error which does not occur when executed in command prompt)

Both Windows and server(ubuntu; it uses django as framework) use same version of Python - 3.5.2

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the part of the code which gives me error (local variable 'district' referenced before assignment) only on server.

```
def GetDistrict_driver(addr):

    district = ''

    if addr == 'Seoul':
        district = 'S1'
    elif addr == 'Incheon':
        district = 'A1'
    elif addr == 'Daejeon':
        district = 'B1'
    elif addr == 'Gwangju':
        district = 'C1'
    elif addr == 'Daegu':
        district = 'D1'
    elif addr == 'Ulsan':
        district = 'E1'
    elif addr == 'Busan':
        district = 'F1'

    return district
```

**Error from server**
[image]

Comment: are you sure both files are identical. Because based on the fragment, that's impossible. How did you transfer your file to the server? Did you inspect that nothing went wrong during transferring the file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. I made sure the files are identical over and over again. I have transfered the file via git using push and pull.

Comment: I can't see how the error arises from this code, my guess is that 1 version has a typo in the `return district` line or there is more relevant code you don't show

Comment: At which line is this error reported?

Comment: @Maciek on `return district`

Comment: What kind of newlines do you use? maybe put `print(locals())` before return and see what's in the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

For the server try this command:

```
python3 file.py
```

**Edited:**
In some linux based os there is difference calling python scripts with "python" and "python3" - first one calls the python2.7 interpreter and the second one - python 3 interpreter.

Comment: First, that is not always true, `python` may be an alias for `python3` and second, that would not explain the error anyway

Comment: @stefan.stt I have edited my post which shows that it is using 3.5.2.

Comment: @smchae ok, I will try to think of another possible reason.